# Show to show php object um html modal

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to show a object in a html modal. Since I don't know the structure beforehand, and the child properties can also be objects or arrays, a simple recursive function seemed to be the way to go, but Im not sure. I have this:

```
<?php
class LogHelper extends Helper
{
    public function warningLogError($body_error)
    {
        $data = [];
        $html = '';
        $html .= "<div name='bodyErrosr' class = 'form-group'>";
        $html .= "<div class = 'alert alert-warning' role = 'alert'>";
 
        if (!empty($body_error)) {
            foreach($body_error as $key => $value) {
                $html .= "<li><b>" . $key . "= " . $value. "</b></li>";
            }
     
        } else {
            $html .= "<li><b>" . 'Error!' . "</b></li>";
        }

        $html .= "</ul>";
        $html .= "</div>";
        $html .= "</div>";

        return $html;
    }
}
```

But I don't know the structure beforehand, sometimes I receive an object inside object multiple times. How is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/var-dumper

This also handles circular references (where print_r/vardump fail)

Comment: I use php version 7.2.28. This function works to 8.1 or higher.

Comment: There are older versions, running on older php version:

https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/var-dumper#v5.3.14

Always try to upgrade your software reasonably. Php 7.4 has just reached end of life!